# Can you write json with more than 2 levels with SAS proc json?

Tags: json, sas, hierarchical-data

I have to create a somewhat complex json file from SAS data, farely similar to what SAS creates in its [documentation on the JSON Procedure](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1n0o64iiv77win10abhx582as2s.htm)

```json
[
  "Vehicles",
  [
    "Truck",
    [
      "Greater than $26000",
      {
        "Asia": [
          {
            "Make": "Nissan",
            "Model": " Titan King Cab XE",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "Asia",
            "MSRP": 26650
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Europe": [
        ]
      },
      {
        "USA": [
          {
            "Make": "Cadillac",
            "Model": " Escalade EXT",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "USA",
            "MSRP": 52975
          },
          {
            "Make": "Chevrolet",
            "Model": " Avalanche 1500",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "USA",
            "MSRP": 36100
          },
          {
            "Make": "Chevrolet",
            "Model": " Silverado SS",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "USA",
            "MSRP": 40340
          },
          {
            "Make": "Chevrolet",
            "Model": " SSR",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "USA",
            "MSRP": 41995
          },
          {
            "Make": "Ford",
            "Model": " F-150 Supercab Lariat",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "USA",
            "MSRP": 33540
          },
          {
            "Make": "GMC",
            "Model": " Sierra HD 2500",
            "Type": "Truck",
            "Origin": "USA",
            "MSRP": 29322
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

However, this solution requires you to know the possible values of 'origin'  and that makes it impossible for me to copy and modify the example code

```
%let vehicleType=Truck;
%let minCost=26000;
proc json out="C:\Users\sasabc\JSON\WriteOpenArrayOutput.json" nosastags pretty;
   write open array;
       write values "Vehicles";
       write open array;
           write values "&vehicleType";
           write open array;
               write values "Greater than $&minCost";
               /*********** Asian ***********************/
               %let originator=Asia;
               write open object;
                   write values "&originator";
                   write open array;
                       export sashelp.cars(where=((origin = "&originator")  and 
                                                  (type   = "&vehicleType") and 
                                                  (MSRP   > &minCost)           )
                                           keep=make model type origin MSRP);
                   write close; /* data values */
               write close; /* Asia */
               /*********** European ***********************/
               %let originator=Europe;
               write open object;
                   write values "&originator";
                   write open array;
                       export sashelp.cars(where=((origin = "&originator")  and 
                                                  (type   = "&vehicleType") and 
                                                  (MSRP   > &minCost)           )
                                           keep=make model type origin MSRP);
                   write close; /* data values */
               write close; /* Europe */
               /*********** American ***********************/
               %let originator=USA;
               write open object;
                   write values "&originator";
                   write open array;
                       export sashelp.cars(where=((origin = "&originator")  and 
                                                  (type   = "&vehicleType") and 
                                                  (MSRP   > &minCost)           )
                                           keep=make model type origin MSRP);
                   write close; /* data values */
               write close; /* USA */
           write close; /* expensive */
       write close; /* vehicleType */
   write close; /* cars */
run;
```

Does anyone have a solution that is more generic/offers more flexibility, but which offers the same guarantee that is creates valid json as `proc json` does?

Comment: When I have to write JSON using SAS I approach it in one of 2 ways: 1. roll my own using data _null_ and put statements, 2. use another tech (such as C#, Python, PowerShell) and call it using the X command. I don't like how SAS handles XML or JSON so I bypass it.

Comment: The JSON written by the documentation example seems very poorly structured.  At least the JSON libref cannot make sense of it.  It creates a separate dataset for each Origin.  Do you have an example of the type of JSON you actually want to write?

Comment: @Tom The actual json I need is hard to understand without knowledge of the business and I am not sure I am allowed to disclose it. I might come up with an example that resembles my real problem closer later.

Comment: @AlanC, If `proc json` does not do the job, I consider `proc lua`, as it has better integration with SAS data sets (at least in SAS 9.5 and earlier) than the languages you list.

Comment: @DirkH, Kind of disagree on better integration. A SAS dataset is both OleDB and ODBC compatible and can easily be read using C#. Even the SAS metadata is accessible via C# (and Python). To serialize and deserialize from JSON is a 1 line operation in C#.  For operations that involve more modern tech, I prefer more modern means but everyone needs to use what they are comfortable with.

Comment: @AlanC  In Lua, if you know the library reference and tablename (libname & memname), you can read a table into a Lua data structure. I don't thinks it is that easy in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PROC JSON to write a file in that manner then you will need to use some code generation.  You could use macro code, but since the list of ORIGIN values is in data already you could just use a data step to generate the code.

So generate the repetitive code to a file:

```
filename code temp;

proc sort data=sashelp.cars(keep=origin) out=origins nodupkey;
  by origin;
run;

data _null_;
  set origins;
  file code;
  put 'write open object;'
    / 'write values ' origin :$quote. ';'
    / 'write open array;'
    / 'export sashelp.cars(keep=make model type origin MSRP'
    / ' where=((' origin = :$quote. ')'
    / '   and (type   = "&vehicleType")'
    / '   and (MSRP   > &minCost)'
    / ' ));' 
    / 'write close;'
    / 'write close;'
  ;
run;
```

Then %INCLUDE the file at the point where you want it to run.

```
proc json .... ;
 ....
%include code / source2;
 ....
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for at least two good ideas: using $quote. and writing code to a temp file to %include.